# How to build service Android with appcelerator

Tags: javascript, service, appcelerator

I'm building a service with appcelerator studio. This is the code that I have building in **Index.js** page:

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent( { url: 'myservice.js' } );
// Service should run its code every 2 seconds.
intent.putExtra('interval', 60000);
// A message that the service should 'echo'
//intent.putExtra('message_to_echo', 'Bo uscirà questo messaggio?');

var service = Titanium.Android.createService(intent);
service.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info('Service code resumes, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});
service.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info('Service code pauses, iteration ' + e.iteration);
    if (e.iteration === 1) {
        var _model = Alloy.createModel("ServiceDAO", {
            ID : 1,
            ServiceRunning: 0,
            ApplicationRunning: 0
        });
    _model.save();    
    }
});
service.start();
```

Now when I try to start the application, the **myservice.js** is execute every 60 second, but I have two problem:

1) when the service is running, I have a performance problem with interface
2) If I close the application, the service is not running.

So how can I implement a service with appcelerator that run in background also when the app is not running?

Comment: you probably need to build a module for that

Comment: can you explain me how can I build a module for that

Comment: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Development+Guide

Answer (score 0):

I tried this once: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Services-section-43287937_AndroidServices-ServiceCode and seems to work fine.
To log even with the app closed, you should use ADB logcat.
Also, don't forget to include it in your tiapp.xml like:

```
<services>
    <service url="your_service_name.js" type="interval"/>
</services>
```

Comment: I have just insert this code, on my Tiapp.xml 
And my service works, but only if the application is running

Comment: yesterday I noticed that it takes a little to ADB log my code after I kill the app. I have a log every 10 seconds, but when I close my app, it takes around 2 minutes, than starts again to log every 10 seconds.
BTW, I'm using ```adb logcat | grep "TiAPI"``` to log Titanium API only